# How to Format CSV to ARRAY?

Tags: php, arrays, format

Can someone show me how to easily **format an array** with values like this?
I have a CSV file with values like below:

```
27383,15.99
80448,19.99
132876,11.99
150438,120
```

**This is the format I would like:**

```
$array[0]['id'] = 27838
$array[0]['price'] = 15.99
$array[1]['id'] = 80448
$array[2]['price'] = 19.99
```

What I have now is:

```
$data = file_get_contents('id_and_price.csv');
$data = explode(',', $data);
print_r($data);

//foreach($data as $d) {
//  echo $d;
//}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$f = fopen('filename', 'r');
$arr = array();
while ($l = fgetcsv($f)) {
  $arr[] = array_combine(array('id', 'price'), $l);
}
var_dump($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this quite easily with [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/fgetcsv):

```
$arr = array();
$header = array('id', 'price');

$file = fopen('id_and_price.csv', 'r');
while($item = fgetcsv($file))
{
   $arr[] = array_combine($header, $item);
}

print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use php explode...
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
$csv  = "piece1,piece2,piece3,piece4,piece5,piece6";
$array = explode(",", $csv);
echo $array[0]; // piece1
echo $array[1]; // piece2
```

Comment: just noticed you aready have this! I would suggest if you ony have the 2 vaues, to try detecting odd/evens. set up a count $i=0. then use if($i%) to detect odd nunbrs and use that to mod your array keys